# Use present continuous instead of present simple in a sentence

Tags: grammaticality, present-tense, present-continuous

I saw on my english book the exercise's sentence:

> According to many, Google is changing our lives by broadening our knowledge of the world.

Is it also correct "changes" instead of "is changing" in this sentence?
I think so because present simple is about permanent situations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, both are correct. "Is changing" puts more emphasis on the current moment: the change that is happening right now. But you could also write "Google changes our lives", and the meaning would be *almost* the same.

Comment: Please be aware that answers on ELU are expected to be accompanied by sound supporting references, linked and attributed. If you think this is too simple to need such, it's too simple a question for ELU and shouldn't be answered.